# django-admin.py is using Django 1.11 instead of Django 2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have both python2 and python3 installed on my ubuntu machine.

Also I have both versions of Django[Django 1.11 and Django 2.1.3] 
Installed.

Whenever I make a new project in django.

**django-admin** is using Django 1.11 by default

How do I create a project in Django 2.1.3 instead of Django 1.11??
I tried using virtualenv but its not working correctly ??

Comment: Use virtual environments.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I have resolved it now. You can do the following steps:

1) Run `which django-admin` it should show the path to django-admin 1.11.

2) Copy the path printed after above command. Let path be

3) Run the following command: `rm -rf <path>`

Answer (score 0):

First, create virtual environment. for Django 2.1 install python 3.5/3.6/3.7 virtualenv.

```
Django version     Python versions
1.11               2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 (added in 1.11.17)
2.0                3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7
2.1, 2.2           3.5, 3.6, 3.7
```

Then activate virtualenv.

```
source your_virtualenv_name/bin/activate
```

Then install Django specific version like:

```
pip install Django==2.1.4
```

Comment: So, what's your problem

Comment: Whenever I run django-admin startprojects <project-name> by default  its using Django version 1.11

Comment: if your virtual env for django==2.1.4 then django-admin startproject project_name automatically use django 2.1.4

Comment: activate virtual env the check version of python in virtualenv then check django version

Comment: I tried but its still not working .Can you tell me the step by step procedure with commands.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Removing the old Django version works for me.